# 'Thanks for.. ' or 'I thank you for...'

Tags: speech, email, correspondence

I was wondering if the expression "I thank you for your answer" isn't nicer than " Thank you for your answer".

For comparison, saying "I thank you" in French is nicer because the person who says it is more involved than when he/she simply says "Thank you for ...".

Is it the same thing in English?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, there's minimal difference.  It really depends on the formality of the context.

> I thank you for...

would be better suited under *Dear....* in a letter (or nowadays, an email).

> Thank you for...

usually belongs in more casual speech.  There's no real difference in how 'involved' either one is.   It depends on the context.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/types-of-english-formal-informal-etc/formal-and-informal-language

Comment: Thank you for your answer :-) I will use "I thank you for..." in my future formal emails.